# Why my wordpress ajax isn't calling in frontend javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using ajax in js file. but now getting error in that **"**mydomain.com/my_ajax.ajax_url** not found 404"** in console logs.

here is my js file (demo.js) code. tried all methods but no solution--

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "my_ajax.ajax_url",
        data: { action: "data_fetch", keyword: input }
});
```

**my functions.php -------**

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hindrise_script');

```
function my_enqueue() {

 wp_register_script('plugin-ajaxJs', CHILD_URL . '/js/demo.js', __FILE__);
    wp_enqueue_script('plugin-ajaxJs');
    
    wp_localize_script('plugin-ajaxJs', 'my_ajax', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
    
}
```

Comment: `url: my_ajax.ajax_url,` remove the quotes

Answer (score 0):

The function name is different than what you have defined in add_action. Use the same name in the add_action and the function name:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hindrise_script');
function hindrise_script() {

 wp_register_script('plugin-ajaxJs', CHILD_URL . '/js/demo.js', __FILE__);
    wp_enqueue_script('plugin-ajaxJs');
    
    wp_localize_script('plugin-ajaxJs', 'my_ajax', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
    
}
```

Also in the JS file remove the quotes for the passing variable:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
        data: { action: "data_fetch", keyword: input }
});
```